# JQuery debug commented out

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2013

I have a problem with my web project with visual studio and jquery code.
It's similar to this question:
[jQuery code still being executed even after being commented out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664025/jquery-code-still-being-executed-even-after-being-commented-out)
but still doesn't work.

I've a `<div>` vertically moved with scroll (jquery script). 
I use google libraries and this perfectly works.

I would like to add some constraints to the jquery script but, after some useless attempts, I've tried to commented out the code to know a new fact:

running the code in chrome (or ie) I can still move the `<div>`, this because commentig out some jquery code "has zero effect on the server-side processing".

I've already try this:

- delete/commented out `<script src ..>`
- delete/commented out jquery scrip
- delete cache chrome, ie

How I can solve this problem? Sorry if this seems a stupid question, but this time I can not solve by myself (just reading online, forum etc).

NEWS:
I've tried:

-[Visual Studio Development Server not updating css and javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563648/visual-studio-development-server-not-updating-css-and-javascript)

-[visual studio not updating html / javascript to server / browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646447/visual-studio-not-updating-html-javascript-to-server-browser)

and nothing works, still jquery run after deleting all jquery scripts.

Comment: Why did you not post relevant source code? An individual problem needs an individual solution. It is so hard to understand? You can add source code by using the "edit"-link underneath your post.

Comment: learn about commenting javascript : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comments.asp

Comment: reporter, I think code is not relevant for this question, infact deleting all the jquery code and all script src, the scroll still works. But if someone need it I'll post the code immediately.